# req. 'connection' is @deprecated — since v13.0.0 - Use socket instead

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to get the client's IP using Express:

```
const ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
```

When mouseover the req.connection in VS Code I get a warning:

```
(property) IncomingMessage.connection: Socket
@deprecated — since v13.0.0 - Use socket instead.

'connection' is deprecatedts(6385)
```

How to implement the 'socket instead' / what is the proper way to find the IP of the client?

Answer (score 8):

You have just to replace `req.connection.remoteAddress` with `req.socket.remoteAddress` in the [http package documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_connection) `request.connection` is flagged as **Deprecated** and It's an alias of `request.socket`, you can directly use `request.socket`

`request.socket` is an instance of [net.Socket](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket) you  check all available methods [here](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket)

Comment: As I found in Node docs, it is correct to use `req.socket.localAddress` instead of `req.socket.remoteAddress` See example here https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_socket

Comment: `req.socket.localAddress` presentation the local IP address the remote client is connecting on, and `req.socket.remoteAddress` refer to the remote address. they don't refer to the same value

Comment: the example is confusing.  It’s making a request to determine the local ip address.

Answer (score 0):

Just type req.socket.remoteAddress instead and you are good to go!