# express req.connection.remoteAddress is sometimes undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using express to receive and process various HTTP requests in my application. I need to have the client's remote IP address and I am obtaining it in the following way:

```
function onPostRequest(req, res) {
    var reqDate = new Date().getTime();
    let srcIP = req.connection.remoteAddress;
    debug.log(4, 'arif', 'Request POST URL: ' + req.originalUrl + ' from: ' + srcIP + ', connection destroyed: ' + req.connection.destroyed);
    [ . . . ]
}
```

but the value of `req.connection.remoteAddress` is sometimes `undefined`. I have a client (running on an Arduino) that is sending around 30 of those POST requests in a row and only some of them have that issue. What is more it is always a different subset of connections. I looked into the tcpdump of the traffic and found out that when the issue happens express is immediately sending RST segment after last byte of the request. The `req.connection.destroyed` is always `false`.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Perhaps this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67261676/req-connection-is-deprecated-since-v13-0-0-use-socket-instead which says `req.connection.remoteAddress` has been deprecated and you should be using `req.socket.remoteAddress`.

Comment: I tried `req.socket.remoteAddress` and `req.ip` too, along with `req.connection.remoteAddress` they are all three either `undefined` or all three contain valid IP address.

Comment: Either you've found some sort of bug or your code is doing something wrong.  You don't show much of your code so we can't really advise on the latter.  I would suggest trying to reproduce it in the simplest possible http server app using only the `http` module.  If you can, then file a bug and document exactly how to reproduce it.  The key to a good bug report is isolating the smallest app that you can reproduce it in and then successfully describing how to reproduce it such that a developer can reproduce it themselves.